# How to create admin panel for yii 1.x framework, also integrate a custom theme such that gii crud auto-generate and auto-integrate css in views?

Tags: yii

As my question say, I need to create an admin panel for yii 1.x framework, also I have a custom theme I downloaded for yii 1.x. I want to integrate it such that gii CRUD when generate views theme will auto-integrate css in views.

I want the above to work only with the admin panel? Or if there's another way, it's also welcome.

There's a catch, my front end website is already completed with a different UI. It was a theme but I didn't used crud for it. I have created every thing manually to get better command on it. For admin panel I want to use CRUD.

I checked this question, [creating admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905011/creating-admin-panel-in-yii) in stackoverflow search, my problem is slightly different.

Comment: You can set a different layout for your admin controllers in the Controller base class (`protected/components/Controller.php`), or in the controllers or actions themselves

Comment: @BrettGregson Can you please feed me with more information? How to set up admin panel like you are suggesting? How to set up Yii based login for admin. Or is it good to make custom Admin login?